# Нужна ли запятая перед союзом «и» или же необходима точка с запятой?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение, и

*Поглощая твоё присутствие, я расцвету, **и** мои побеги нежно оплетут тебя.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Поглощая твоё присутствие, я расцвету, и мои побеги нежно оплетут тебя.***

**Запятая** в таком предложении является  **основным знаком,** поэтому именно запятая здесь и ставится.

А вот постановку **точки с запятой** в сложном предложении при наличии сочинительного союза ***И*** нужно объяснять. Нельзя сказать, что это будет ошибкой в любом случае. Правила разрешают это, **но при особых условиях.**

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134#pp134

Перед союзами И, ДА (в значении И) точка с запятой ставится лишь в том случае, когда они соединяют два предложения, **которые без них были бы разделены точкой**: Скоро весь сад, согретый солнцем, обласканный, ожил, и капли росы, как алмазы, засверкали на листьях; и старый, давно запущенный сад в это утро казался таким молодым, нарядным (Ч.);

Проверяем: *Поглощая твоё присутствие, я расцвету. Мои побеги нежно оплетут тебя.*

Нет, **точку поставить нельзя**. Такой текст выглядит некорректно, так как простые предложения в составе сложного тесно связаны по смыслу.

Следовательно, ставим запятую, а не точку с запятой.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Добавлю для  полной ясности, в чем  состоит суть **проверки Розенталя**.

Я думаю, что это **интонационная проверка**, которая имеет **универсальный** характер.  Другими словами,  так можно проверить обоснованность выбора **точки с запятой** для сложных предложений любого вида  (с сочинительной, подчинительной или бессоюзной связью).

Дело в том, что интонация предложения при постановке **точки с запятой** ближе **к точке, чем к запятой**,  отличие только **в длительности паузы**.

Если автор ставит точку с запятой,  то он может **для проверки** прочитать предложение с разделяющей точкой.   Эти варианты будут **мало различаться** между собой по интонации,  а смысловая связь между простыми предложениями будет выглядеть ослабленной, что характерно и для точки с запятой.

При этом речь **не идет о действительной замене:** каждый знак должен органично вписываться в текст.

Comment: 1. _Нельзя сказать, что это будет ошибкой **в любом случае**._ Простите, Sharon, но именно так никто и не говорил. Мне кажется, что я написала "очень конкретно": "В этом случае по правилам перед "и" ставится запятая. Постановка точки с запятой является ошибкой". 2. _Нет, точку поставить нельзя._ А чего ж нельзя-то? В чем некорректность?

Comment: Вот почему меня так не любят, все критикуют, что за карма такая! Справедливости никакой… Вот, к примеру, первый ответ: он вообще  безо всяких объяснений,  а всем нравится. А  я же никого не комментирую, отвечаю на вопрос строго по тексту (про БСП не рассказываю, там же нет БСП).  Привожу правило Розенталя для ССП с союзом И, делаю проверку. Может, немного категорично звучит, что нельзя поставить точку, но тогда уж надо весь текст видеть. Может, автор любит парцелляцию, и у него все предложения из трех-четырех слов. Но тогда и точку с запятой не запрещено ставить. Авторский знак,  однако!

Answer (score 1):

Нет, точка с запятой здесь не нужна. Вполне достаточно запятой.

Answer (score 1):

*Поглощая твоё присутствие, **я расцвету**, и мои **побеги** нежно **оплетут** тебя.*

На смысл отвлекаться не будем (контекста-то нет) — рассмотрим только пунктуацию.
Это сложносочиненное предложение, в котором две основы (два подлежащих и два сказуемых): *я расцвету* и *побеги оплетут.* Они связаны между собой сочинительным союзом "и". В этом случае по правилам перед "и" ставится запятая.
Постановка точки с запятой является ошибкой.

[Запятая перед союзом «И»](https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/315-zapyatayaperedsyuzomi.html)

**Точках запятой** ставится в ***бессоюзном*** сложном предложении в следующих случаях:

1)) если предикативные части отдалены друг от друга по смыслу или значительно распространены и имеют внутри себя запятые: *Изумрудные лягушата прыгают под ногами; между корней, подняв золотую головку, лежит уж и стережёт их* (М. Г.);

2)) если бессоюзное сложное предложение распадается на части (группы предложений), в свою очередь образующие бессоюзные сложные предложения: *Лёгкая пыль жёлтым столбом поднимается и несётся по дороге; далеко разносится дружный топот, лошади бегут, навострив уши* (Т.);

3)) если бессоюзное соединение частей предложения сочетается с союзным (нередко между частями предложения, соединенными без союзов, ставится **точка с запятой**, а между частями, связанными союзом, — **запятая**): *Было серо, тускло, безотрадно, хоть огонь зажигай; все жаловались на холод, и дождь стучал в окна* (Ч.).

[Запятая и точка с запятой в бессоюзном сложном предложении](https://old-rozental.online/punctum_uk.php?pid=337)

Answer (score 0):

Точка с запятой не нужна, не буду повторять уже сказанное.
А вот в отношении необходимости запятой есть сомнения. Фраза настолько вычурная, что грамматику её однозначно определить, боюсь, не сможет и сам автор. А смысл - и подавно.
Так вот, если деепричастный оборот относится только у первой части "я расцвету", то да запятая нудна. Ну а если ко всей остальной части ("я расцвету, и мои побеги нежно оплетут тебя") - то это сложносочиненное предложение с общим членом - и тут в правилах некоторая купюра. о ли нужна эта запятая, то ли нет... Большинство все-таки за то, что по аналогии со случаем СПП запятая не требуется.

Но перво-наперво вопрос в том, кто там у автора кого поглощает. Побеги - они тоже назначены поглощать "твое присутвие"? Или только "я"?